# Sidebar not positioning correctly

Tags: html, css

Basically, I don't understand why the  isn't at the top right? It positions itself at the bottom, even though by my understanding it should be on the top right?

See JSfiddle for detailed code

http://jsfiddle.net/5JhMj/

```
#content section {
padding: 4%;
width: 70%;
float: left;
background-color: white;
margin-bottom:8%;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
```

}

```
aside {
width: 30%;
float: right;
background-color: green;
```

}

Comment: The isse starts in your HTML -> Since you got elements before `aside` element, this last one only shows after. You can **1)** Add `position: absolute` to your `aside` element or **2)** change your HTML layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are floating your sidebar around your last section element.

Instead of this, wrap your sections around another container which you float. Then let your sidebar float aside that new container.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="section-container">
        <section>...</section>
    </div>
    <aside>
        ...
    </aside>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.section-container{
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}

aside {
    width: 29%;
    float: right;
    background-color: green;
}
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/5JhMj/2/

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is put your aside before `section`

like

```
<div class="container">
<aside>
<h1>placeholder</h1>
</aside>
<section>
...
...
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/5JhMj/1/)**